# Nuxt performance in the lighthouse

Tags: performance, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

Despite my code is very simple I do not know why my Nuxt performance is too low in the lighthouse. My Nuxt web app is deployed with the name [hadicodes.com](https://hadicodes.com) and you can check it out yourselves online.

This is my `nuxt.config`:

```
const sitemap = require('./modules/sitemap/sitemap.js');
import redirectSSL from 'redirect-ssl'
const isDev = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production');
module.exports = {
  head: {
    title: 'hadicodes',
    meta: [
      {
        name: 'viewport',
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: ''
      },
      {
        name: 'format-detection',
        content: 'telephone=no'
      }
    ],
    link: [{
      rel: 'icon',
      type: 'image/x-icon',
      href: '/favicon.ico'
    }]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '@/assets/css/changeeffect.css',
    '@/assets/css/costum.css',
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '@/plugins/vue-html2pdf', mode: 'client' }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [],
  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: "/", handler: "~/server/redirect.js" },
    redirectSSL.create({
      enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
     }),
  ],
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxt/content',
    [
      'bootstrap-vue/nuxt', {
        icons: true
      }
    ],
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    [
      "nuxt-i18n",
      {
        lazy: true,
        langDir: "lang/",
        locales: [{
            code: "en",
            name: "English",
            file: "en.json"
          },
          {
            code: "nl",
            name: "Nederlands",
            file: "nl.json"
          },
          {
            code: "fr",
            name: "Français",
            file: "fr.json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    '@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
    ['@nuxtjs/amp', {
      css: '~/assets/css/amp/default.amp.css',
     }],
     '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
    // TODO: Remove it if you want to eject from codeSandbox
  ],
  sitemap:sitemap,
  fontawesome:{
    component:'fa',
    icons: {
      solid: ['faHouse','faCamera','faAddressCard','faBlog','faPersonDigging','faPhone','faLanguage','faStar','faStarHalfStroke',],
      regular:['faStar']
    }
  },
  
  content:{},
  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {},

  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en',
      name: 'hadicodes.com',
      theme_color: "#FFF",
      start_url: '/',
    },
    workbox: {
      dev: isDev,
      workboxURL: !isDev?'./node_modules/workbox-cdn/workbox/workbox-sw.js':null,

      config: {
          modulePathPrefix: !isDev?'./node_modules/workbox-cdn/workbox':null,

      },
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  server: {
    port: 3500 // default: 3000
  },
  generate:{
    dir: '../docs',
    ignore:[
      '.nuxt', // buildDir
    'static', // dir.static
    'dist', // generate.dir
    'node_modules',
    '.**/*',
    '.*',
    'README.md'
    ]
  },
  build: {
    extend (config, ctx) {
      config.resolve.symlinks = false
    },
    babel: {
      compact: true
    },
    extend(config, { isDev , isClient }) {
      if (isClient && !isDev) {
        config.optimization.splitChunks.maxSize = 200000
      }
      if (isClient) {
        config.devtool = 'source-map'
      }
    },
  },
  render: {
    http2: {
      push: true,
      bundleRenderer: {
        shouldPreload: (file, type) => {
          return ['script', 'style', 'font'].includes(type)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  telemetry: false
}
```

This is my code for the first page

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <b-row>
        <b-col class="mt-5">
          <h5>This is me. (4cm x 6cm passport photo)</h5>
          <h2>Hadi MAJ</h2>
        </b-col>
        <b-col align="center">
          <b-img-lazy rel="preload" class="w-100" src="/images/hero-img.png" alt="hero-img" />
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
      <b-card-group deck align="center">
        <b-card>
          <b-card-title>
            <div>
              <b-icon icon="card-image"></b-icon>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
              <h5>Web design</h5>
            </div>
          </b-card-title>
          <b-card-text>
            <client-only>
            <NuxtContent :document="posts[0]" />
            </client-only>
          </b-card-text>
          <!-- <b-card-text class="small text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</b-card-text> -->
        </b-card>
        <b-card>
          <b-card-title>
            <div>
              <b-icon icon="tools"></b-icon>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
              <h5>Web Development</h5>
            </div>
          </b-card-title>
          <b-card-text>
            <client-only>
            <NuxtContent :document="posts[1]" />
            </client-only>
```

1. My photo is lazy loaded. Why lighthouse is asking for "Preload the image used by the LCP element in order to improve your LCP time".
2. How can I get rid of "Script Evaluation" ?

The speed is not very bad but the performance of the lighthouse is a disaster. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can check yourself online how to achieve better TTI/TBT. Another solution is to check all available performance points from a brand new project and try to reduce the hydration time, make use of SSG, avoid global import of plugins, double check the final bundle size from webpack, limit the amount of global loaded CSS etc... You can also check this [kind of article](https://dev.to/jacobandrewsky/performance-checklist-for-vue-and-nuxt-cog). The idea would be to see incrementally what is impacting the vitals as much. Also, web vitals are harder to reach 100% every new months, it's normal.

Comment: Your photo should not be lazy-loaded because it's seen straight on the page. Also, I do recommend reading the according page: https://web.dev/optimize-lcp/

Answer (score 0):

Alongside my comment, you could probably double check the side of plugins you're importing globally and that are affecting your page in initial load.

https://bundlephobia.com/package/vue-html2pdf@1.8.0

`vue-html2pdf` is **quite** heavy as you can see. Since you're loading it globally, it's not helping with the JS parse/execution time.

Also, consider maybe some partial hydration meta frameworks like:

- [AstroJS](https://astro.build/)
- [MarkoJS](https://markojs.com/)
- [Qwik](https://qwik.builder.io/)

If you want to totally skip the hydration price.

Of course, some solutions are available on Nuxt's side too by using [vue-lazy-hydration](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vue-lazy-hydration).

Comment: -thx. how can i get rid of "Script Evaluation" in "Minimize main-thread work "?

Comment: @user10029059 this is happening because your browser needs to download, parse and execute a heavy chunk of JS code. Solution to that? Don't use such heavy chunk of code as explained in my answer pretty much. Some alternative or loading it locally is probably the best approach, code splitting etc can come in handy too ofc.